# Angular.js ui Router. element only visible with a given child

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I've a view an abstract view state like

**project.detail**

and child states like

**project.detail.settings**

**project.detail.Summary**

Now in the abstract project.detail view i have a button should be only be visible when the view projects.detail.summary is shown.

I could image that each child view may trigger a angular.js service which results ind changing the model of the abstract view. but isn't there an easier way ?

Something like ng-show="childView == 'summary' ?

my viewstates look like this:

```
   var projectsDetail = {
        name: 'projects.detail',
        templateUrl: viewPath + '/projects/projects.Detail.html',
        controller: 'projectsDetailCtrl',
        abstract:true,
        url: '/:id',
    };

   var projectsDetailChangesets = {
        name: 'projects.detail.changesets',
        templateUrl: viewPath + '/projects/projects.detail.changesets.html',
        controller: 'projectsDetailCtrl',
        parent:projectsDetail,
        url: '/changesets',
    };

    var projectSummaries= {
        name: 'projects.detail.Summary',
        templateUrl: viewPath + '/projects/projects.Summary.html',
        controller: 'projectsSettingsCtrl',
        parent: projectsDetail,
        url: '/settings',
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it in one of two ways. You could fiddle with ui-sref-active, which adds a class to an element based on whether or not you're in a particular state.

http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-sref-active

(note that the most recent release to ui-router changed how ui-sref-active works and added ui-sref-active-eq, which is the legacy version).

Or you could do it with regular ng-ifs using a predicate that looks like `$state.includes('projects.detail.Summary')}` instead. In that case, you'll need to actually add $state to your $scope. When I have to do that, I do: `$scope.$state = $state` in my controller, which feels kinda like a hack, but it works.